# Carregar um componente em outro template

Tags: layout, template, angular-8

Tenho um aplicativo em angular com um drawer.
O aplicativo funciona normalmente exibindo o seu conteúdo no painel central do drawer/conteúdo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto ao clicar em um botão preciso abrir uma nova aba no navegador mas exibindo outro componente em template diferente do padrão.

Pelo que entendi devo alterar o módulo de rotas especificando uma rota filha para que o componente utilize um router-outlet de outro componente, e não o do componente padrão (app.component).
Para isto criei um componente "ClearLayoutComponent" com um router-outlet somente, e especifiquei no módulo de rotas que a rota "paciente/:id" deverá usar o template do componente "ClearLayoutComponent".

```
const routes: Routes = [

{
path: 'pessoas',
component: ListaPessoasComponent,
data: { title: 'Pessoas' }
},
{
path: '',
component: ClearLayoutComponent,
children: [
{
     path: 'paciente/:id',
     component: PacienteComponent,
     data: { title: 'Paciente' }
}]}];
```

O método que chamo para abrir a aba é este:

```
 Editar(id:number){
 window.open(`./paciente/${id}` ,"_blank");
 }
```

Tudo funciona, mas ainda sim o template do app.component é exibido na nova aba.